# Circular Arrangement: There are atleast two boys between any two adjacent girls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The problem statement goes something like this

> How many ways are there to arrange $6$ girls and $15$ boys in a circle such that there are at least two boys between any two adjacent girls?

Here is how I tried to solving it.

1. I started by first arranging girls in $(6-1)!$ ways.
2. Next I decided to arrange $6$ boys out of $15$ in the gap between the arranged girls.
3. Again I did the same for remaining $9$ boys.
4. Finally, choose $3$ out of $6$ gaps for arranging the remaining $3$ boys.

Altogether, I got
$$5! \cdot {{15}\choose{6}} \cdot 6! \cdot {{9}\choose{6}} \cdot 6! \cdot {{6}\choose{3}} \cdot 3!$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$ I could say that there are at least two boys in between two adjacent girls.

Since I do not have the solution of this problem, I am really not sure about my approach. Am I making a sensible argument? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is incorrect since it only allows for gaps of size 2 and 3 and no other size gaps.  You will never have a gap of size 5 for example despite that being a possible valid arrangement, e.g. $gbbgbbgbbgbbgbbgbbbbb$ arranged in a circle.  As a result, you have undercounted.

For a correct approach, begin by designating one of the girls as being special (*for example, the shortest girl*).  Describe all circular arrangements of the table instead as arrangements in a row where our special girl is furthest left in the row.

We will have something along the lines of an arrangement like:

$$\color{red}{G}(b\dots b)G(b\dots b)G(b\dots b)G(b\dots b)G(b\dots b)G(b\dots b)$$

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ represent the number of boys in each of the respective gaps above.  Choose a solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ from among the solutions to the system:

$$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=15\\ 2\leq x_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$$

Once having chosen a solution $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_6)$, arrange the boys in a line and have the remaining five girls in a line (*remember that we specified our special girl must have been the first in the row*) and have them line up according to the pattern we designated.

Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

> To count the number of solutions to the system, consider a change of variable $y_i=x_i-1$ to instead be counting the solutions to the system $\begin{cases} y_1+y_2+\dots+y_6=9\\1\leq y_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$ and then apply a stars-and-bars argument.

$~$

> There are $\binom{8}{5}$ choices for solution to the system, $5!$ ways to arrange the remaining girls and $15!$ ways to arrange the boys, giving a grand total of $\binom{8}{5}\cdot 5!\cdot 15!$ arrangements.

Comment: This indeed is a very nice solution to this problem. It is not like I am trying to be obsessed with my work, but I still would like to know, whether there is a way to cover that _undercounted_ part and will that be enough to reach the right answer.